# ArgumentOutOfRangeException but the argument isn't out of range

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

I'm using `INotifyPropertyChanged` in WinForms to bind to a `NumericUpDown`.

On my control I have two `NumericUpDown` controls each bound to a different property of the same instance of a view model.

One of them works perfectly, the other throws up two exceptions each time the value is changed.

When my `NumericUpDown` is changed I get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` followed by a `TargetInvocationException`.

As can be seen from the image below, `Value` is not out of range so I'm not sure why `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` is being thrown.  The `TargetInvocationException` is just as puzzling.

[image]

Any ideas where I should be looking to fix this?

Comment: Can you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This makes it far easier to drop this code into a debugger and reproduce your issue. In particular don´t post images of code, but the *actual* code. Btw.: you didn´t provide the value for `value`.

Comment: Better post your code , which makes easier to answer !